# "Invalid type owner for DynamicMethod" error in Nhibernate

Tags: nhibernate, generics

What if you receive the "Invalid type owner for DynamicMethod" error while initializing you NHibernate SessionFactory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you recieve the "Invalid type owner for DynamicMethod" error while initializing you NHibernate SessionFactory then it's pretty likely that you are using generic methods on some of your lazy loaded/proxied classes.

Nhibernate incorporates a reflection optimization that speeds up the creation of proxy classes. This reflection optimization does not play well with generics. The error it throws is "Invalid type owner for DynamicMethod". Not very friendly.

So, to fix this you must either stop using generic methods OR turn off the optimization. To turn off the optimization you must run the following code before you initialize your SessionFactory.

```
NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.UseReflectionOptimizer = false;
```